# Why I cant to insert a list to my other list?

Tags: list

I am trying to print list on list.

```
def compress_text(to_compress):
    n_list=len(to_compress)
    count=1
    z=0
    mylist=[]
    newlist=[]
    for i in range(0,n_list):
        if i==n_list-1:
            break
        elif to_compress[i]==to_compress[i+1]:
            count=count+1
        else:
            newlist=[to_compress[i],count]
            mylist.append(newlist[z])
            count=1
            z=z+1
    print(mylist)    
compress_text("aaabbbccc")
```

What I get on the print is just `['a',3]`

What is the problem here? What I am missing?